# What's a better way to code this?

Tags: c++, casting, queue, breadth-first-search

I'm trying to make a make a program that implements breadth first search using a queue.

```
// Queue.h

    #pragma once
    #include<iostream>

    struct node
     {
      int b1,b2,b3,b4;
      node* link;
     };

struct state
    {
     int b1,b2,b3,b4;
     state* rightChild;
     state* leftChild;
    };

class Queue
{
   private:
    node* front, *rear ;
   public:
        bool enqueue(node n);
        //......
};
```

---

```
  //BFS.cpp
  #include <iostream>
  #include "Queue.h"

  int main()
  {

   struct state
       {
          int b1,b2,b3,b4;
          state* rightChild;
          state* leftChild;
      };

    // now i define all the nodes of the tree, each node is of type state
    Queue Q;        // make a queue
    Q.enqueue(initialState);         //where initialState is the root
    //...

  }
```

the queue I've created stores nodes of type node- whereas the nodes in the tree are of type State. I can't use a copy constructor since both are individual structures. So what's an efficient way to organize the code to make the nodes of the tree be accepted in the queue?

Comment: Use standard library. It's certainly the best way to code this, as it has both the queue and find possibilities.

Comment: Don't duplicate state values in a node, have a node contain a state as a member.